# java convert object array to int array

Tags: java, android

how i can do this? i have an object array id like to convert it to int array

Comment: what does the object array contain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if Object[] objectArray like `objectArray = {2,23,42,3}` then

```
public static Integer[] convert(Object[] objectArray){
  Integer[] intArray = new Integer[objectArray.length];

  for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
   intArray[i] = (Integer) objectArray[i];
  }

  return intArray;
 }
```

if your objectArray is like `Object[] objectArray = new Integer[/*length*/];`

You can simply cast `(Integer []) objectArray;`

Comment: +1 good one ! can be converted into int leveraging Autoboxing feature !

Answer (score 0):

If the content can be casted to `Integer`, you can cast the array to `Integer []` and use its elements as `int`:

```
Object [] arr = new Integer[3];
arr[0] = new Integer(1);
arr[1] = new Integer(2);
arr[2] = 3;
Integer [] newa = (Integer []) arr;
for(int i:newa) {
  System.err.print(i+" "); 
}
```

Otherwise you can create a new `int []` array with the same length as the original and then set the elements in the newly created arrays to the values given by conversion:

```
int [] arr = new int[origarr.length];
arr[0] = convertTo_int(origarr[0]);
// convertTo_int implementation depends on the type of origarr elements.
```